# How do I implement an error recovery system, when the user inputs a string that does not exist?

Tags: python

Goal is to be able to read a file, when the user calls for it. I have successfully implemented this step; User calls the program to read the contents of a file, the program prints it out. However, I am stuck on the error recovery.

If the user inputs a filename that does not exist, the program should prompt the user that it does not exist, and request that they input again.

The program uses the `os` library, which, I use the `os.getcwd()` to list the files available to view. I figured, since it was listing it out, I could set it to a list and it would do one of two things- matching = print the contents of file; no match = prints error. I was not able to do this successfully.

Is there another/better way to do this or is the list idea the way to go?

Here is my code, prior to the list idea. I have omitted the parts that are not necessary to run the code:

```
import os, os.path

QUIT = '8'

COMMANDS = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8')

MENU = """1   List the current directory
2   Move up
3   Move down
4   Number of files in the directory
5   Size of the directory in bytes
6   Search for a file name
7   View the contents of a file
8   Quit the program"""

def main():
    while True:
        print(os.getcwd())
        print(MENU)
        command = acceptCommand()
        runCommand(command)
        if command == QUIT:
            print("Have a nice day!")
            break

def acceptCommand():
    """Inputs and returns a legitimate command number."""
    while True:
        command = input("Enter a number: ")
        if not command in COMMANDS:
            print("Error: command not recognized")
        else:
            return command

def runCommand(command):
    if command == '7':
        viewFile()
        

def viewFile():
    #print files in cwd
    listCurrentDir(os.getcwd())
    fname = input("Enter Filename: ")
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
    print(contents, "\n")

def listCurrentDir(dirName):
    """Prints a list of the cwd's contents."""
    lyst = os.listdir(dirName)
    for element in lyst: print(element)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is my code, after I tried to implement the list idea:

```
def viewFile():
    fileList = []
    fileList = listCurrentDir(os.getcwd())
    fname = input("Enter Filename: ")
    if fname not in fileList:
        print("Error: Filename does not exist.")
        break
    else:
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            contents = f.read()
            print(contents, "\n")
```

Comment: Reason for edit: import line got hidden as it was on the same line as the start of code block.

Comment: I would say test for QUIT before you run the command, `if not command in COMMANDS: return command`, don't hard code number and action, what if you add a command, construct number/menu from array of commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific question, this is the answer, using try and except.

```
def viewFile():
    listCurrentDir(os.getcwd())
    while True:
        fname = input("Enter Filename: ")
        try:  
            with open(fname, 'r') as f:
                contents = f.read()
                print(contents, "\n")
                break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error: File name does not exist. \nPlease try again.")
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say ditch the `os` module, and go for `pathlib`, a more modern and high-level module for performing path/directory/file operations that's part of the standard library:

```
def view_file(): # Prefer snake_case in Python
    from pathlib import Path
    file_name = input("Enter filename:")

    if not (abs_path:=Path.cwd() / file_name).exists() or not abs_path.is_file():
        print("The specified file \"{}\" does not exist!".format(abs_path))
        return
    print("Opening \"{}\"...".format(abs_path))
    print(abs_path.read_text())
```

That being said, you could also just attempt to do a normal `open` wrapped in a try-except block. If the `open` raised a `FileNotFoundError` exception, then you know the file could not be found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think I'll be able to use pathlib, as this is part of my course, and the `os` library was included as part of the starter code (along with camelCase).

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob:

```
import traceback
import glob

def viewFile():
    fileList = glob.glob("*")
    fname = input("Enter Filename:")
    if fname not in fileList:
        print("Error: Filename does not exist.")
        return
    elif not os.path.isfile(fname):
        print("Error: Not a file.")
        return
    else:
        try:
            with open(fname, 'r') as f:
                contents = f.read()
                print(contents, "\n")
        except:
            print("Error while reading the file:")
            print(traceback.format_exc())
```

The magic of glob is that you can use regex and both absolute and relative paths with it so you can do:

`fileList = listCurrentDir(glob.glob("*.txt"))`

or:

`fileList = listCurrentDir(glob.glob("/home/Frankie/*.txt"))`